# Doctrine query doesn't recognize shorthand: building condition based queries

Tags: mysql, database, doctrine

```
public static function getAuctions($other = false)
{
    $q = Doctrine::getTable('auctions')
      ->createQuery('u')
      ->select('TIMEDIFF(ends_at, NOW()) as time, ur.username as username, u.last_bider as last_bider,
         pr.img_path as img_path, u.curr_price as price, pr.title as title, u.ends_at as ends_at,
         ur.bids_left as bids_left')
      ->leftJoin('u.Products pr')
      ->leftJoin('u.sfGuardUser ur')
      ->where('u.ends_at > ?', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - 5))
      ->andWhere('u.status = ?', 'Live');


    ***if($other == true)
        $q->andWhere('time > ?', '01:00:00');***

    $q->orderBy('time');

    return $q->execute();
}
```

This query fails on the if clause, saying that mysql can't find the time column. I did name it "time" above in the start.

If i use

```
if($other == true)
            $q->andWhere('TIMEDIFF(ends_at, NOW()) > ?', '01:00:00');
```

it works, but I don't want to repeat myself.

Any way to fix this (or is there a more practical way of building these condition based queries in doctrine?).

Comment: However you do it, `WHERE TIMEDIFF(ends_at, NOW()) > '01:00:00'` will not be able to use an index on `ends_at` but it'll have to scan the whole table (or at least all rows selected by other conditions). Use `WHERE ends_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The select clause is executed AFTER the where clause so it is not possible to refer to a select clause defined alias in the where clause.

What can be done is to substitute the table with a subselect:

```
select time, id
from (
    select TIMEDIFF(ends_at, NOW()) as time, id
    from auctions
) auctions
```

Don't know if it is worth in your case.